# I Append Input Field and Than i am trying to do fire event on the same input But not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){   //Fetch Questions From JSON File "questions.js"   let
    fetchQuestions = () = {
        $.getJSON("json/questions.json", function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                $(".js-questions").append(`
                   <li class="questions__question"
                     <div
                       <span${value.count}</span
                       ${value.question}
                       <input type="text" class="questions__answer js-answer" answer="${value.answer}" onfocus="focusField(this)"/
                     </div
                   </li
                `);
            });
        });   
    }


    fetchQuestions();
 
 
    let focusField = (element) = {
        $(element).css("background-color", "yellow");   
    }

})
```

Comment: You code works, but notice all your div' span is not closed

Comment: all elements are closed

Comment: Prashanth Benny did that. but the code you posted did not include the last `>` on many tags.

Comment: Look at the code now, I've rolled back to what you posted

Comment: maybe wrong formatted

Comment: I've never seen a formatter or plugin that formats code remove the `>`. My guess is that you forgot to write them

Comment: Hard-coded working example of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/40vg1zrj/